# A Brand New, Festive Rebus!

Tags: knowledge, rebus

> Here is a basic rebus with a common theme!
>   [image]

Comment: are those apples in (2) ?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Peas in a pod I believe

Comment: Yeah, definitely peas! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming the theme is :

> pie because pi day

1.

> Apps + hole = apple pie

2.

> pea +can = pecan pie

3.

> chicken pot pie

4.

> pump + kin + pie = pumpkin pie

5.

> straw + berry + rude + barbed wire = strawberry rhubarb pie

6.

> key + ticks (lyme disease) = key lime pie

Comment: I feel like such an apps hole for figuring out the parts for rebus 1, but thinking of a whole another word altogether..

Comment: Apart from apple and pecan pie, never heard of the others, and don't see the apple pie connection.

Comment: @Sentinel , apphole is phonetically similar to apple.