# A Pi day What Am I?

Tags: riddle

Another Pi day themed puzzle like [my other one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/a-brand-new-festive-rebus).

> I contain 5 letters,
>
> I only have 1 syllable,
>
> I can be referred to as money,
>
> Or I can be the foundation of something wonderful (and quite popular too),
>
> I can come before a word similar to “crazy” to be something sweet,
>
> I have silent letters,
>
> Google describes me as thick and elastic.

**What Am I?**

Comment: Overall this is a good riddle with one obvious right answer. Just a suggestion for the future: clue #4 ("foundation of something wonderful (and quite popular too)") is really vague. The two answerers came up with different interpretations, and my guess (pizza) was different from either of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are:

> Dough

I think the first three lines are self explanatory.

Can be the foundation of something wonderful

> Bread/cookie dough

Can be followed by a word similar to "crazy" to be something sweet

> "Nut", to make doughnut/donut

Has silent letters

> The gh are silent.

Google describes me as thick and elastic

> When you search dough, the little box that pops up describes dough as such.

Comment: You have the correct answer @dooog, good job :D P.S. I saw you posted first so you get a green check very soon.

Answer (score 10):

I'm thinking about:

> dough

- It consists of 5 letters. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- It only has one syllable. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- It can be referred to as money. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- > Think about 'Ben & Jerry's Cookie Dough Ice' :-) It's simply wonderful and popular. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- > Add 'nut' (nuts) and you get the delicious doughnut $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- > 'gh' is a very silent sound. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$
- > http://lmgtfy.com/?q=dough $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Thank you for this riddle!

Comment: You got it, great job! :D +1

Comment: You can also write **\checkmark** to generate $\checkmark$ or **\color{green}{\checkmark}** to generate $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ instead of using $\surd$. Nonetheless, good answer $(+1)$ :D

Comment: No problem :) ${}$